# ARB_texture_storage vs OpenGL hardware version

Tags: opengl

[ARB_texture_storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_texture_storage.txt) is a core feature since OpenGL 4.2. The extension had been released before OpenGL 4.2. I would like to determine what is minimum OpenGL version which has to be supported by hardware to use that extension, for example `glTexStorage2DARB`. The documentations says:

> This extension is written against the OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile
> specification.

Does it mean that GPU should support at least OpenGL 3.2 ?

Comment: It only means that the spec of the ARB extension is based on the OpenGL 3.2 spec. It doesn't give you any guarantee that the extension is available on a hardware that supports OpenGL 3.2, nor that it is not available on hardware that doesn't support 3.2. The only option you have is to check at runtime if the extension is available or not. It's even possible that the same hardware supports the extension with some driver version but not with another one.

Comment: But if hardware supports OpenGL 4.2 that extension has to be supported, right ?

Comment: Yes, when the hardware supports 4.2, it is available for sure. I'm not 100% sure about `glTexStorage2DARB`, but `glTexStorage2D` has to work.

Comment: "*The extension had been released before OpenGL 4.2.*" No, it hadn't. They were released on the same day. "*But if hardware supports OpenGL 4.2 that extension has to be supported, right ?*" No. If the implementation provides you a GL 4.2+ version, it doesn't *have* to expose this extension, because it's functionality is already available to you.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I don't really understand why hardware which supports OpenGL 4.2 may not supports ARB_texture_storage. Could you please explain it in more details in the below answer ?

Comment: @Irbis: I don't know what there is to say. If an implementation is giving you GL 4.2+, then you *already have* the functionality that ARB_texture_storage would provide. *Exactly* that functionality (modulo the elements of the extension that interact with other extensions). So why should an implementation expose the extension when it has already given you the functionality? Equally importantly, if you get a 4.2 implementation, why would you be looking for the ARB_texture_storage extension?

Comment: Ok, now it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARB_texture_storage is not something that is "supported by hardware". By and large, it is an API improvement; it doesn't expose something which some GPUs can do and others cannot.

As such, in the dependencies section, the extension specification states:

> OpenGL ES 1.0, OpenGL ES 2.0 or OpenGL 1.2 is required.

This represents the oldest OpenGL version with which this extension is meaningfully compatible. Of course, you are *highly* unlikely to find 1.2 implementations in the wild, let alone implementations that are still being supported without implementing higher GL versions.

Basically, most hardware that was/is still having its drivers maintained since the time of this extension's release will have an implementation of it. And outside of open source drivers, most of that hardware will be GL 4.x of some form.

Also, this extension does not have `ARB` versions of its functions. This is a compatibility extension; it allows you to use GL 4.2 API functionality on hardware that cannot support GL 4.2 (assuming the driver is updated) without forcing you to rename functions or whatever.